# How to clear label caption?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using label with `OnCtrlcolor` event:

I have set the background color of the label to be the same as the form,

```
  if (iD == IDCmylabel)
      {
        pDC->SetTextColor(blue);
        COLORREF normal = RGB(245, 245, 245);
        pDC->SetBkColor(normal);
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
      }
```

So I was thinking to use toogle:

```
SetWindowTextW("abc..."); // will show the color as expected.
SetWindowTextW(nullptr);  // will remove the text color.
```

However this is not working for me (the caption didn't redraw because it still there).

How do I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to add some more details. But why are you trying to change text on a `OnCtlColor()` handler?

Comment: Hi @AdrianMole, I use OnCtrlcolor to change the text color. it's just my note on form. in some case my value=0 so i need to clear this.

Comment: 1. `"abc"` is not wide. 2. Use an empty string instead of `nullptr`.

Comment: Hi @zdf, I tried `"", L"", " "` but it seems to ignore null or some space. my current solution is use many many space to remove it as this: `L"                                                                                   "`. I hope to find a better way ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL_BRUSH` is a brush that instructs the system to turn any painting operations that use that brush into no-ops. Using it doesn't actually make the control transparent. It just appears to be transparent until (part of it) has been painted.

If you want a control that has a particular background color, irrespective of the the size of text displayed, you're going to have to provide a solid color brush.

The easiest way to do this would be to return a [`DC_BRUSH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getstockobject), with an accompanying call to [`SetDCBrushColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class#setdcbrushcolor) to request the color, i.e.

```cpp
if (iD == IDCmylabel) {
    pDC->SetTextColor(blue);
    COLORREF normal = RGB(245, 245, 245);
    // Still required so that the text background matches that of the rest
    pDC->SetBkColor(normal);
    // Request brush color for the control background
    pDC->SetDCBrushColor(normal);
    // Note: Stock objects do not need to be freed by client code
    return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
}
```

With that you can call `SetWindowText` with arbitrary parameters and get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, this really works for me instead of using wstring(50,' ').c_str(); thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Someone needs to erase the background under the old text.

You are returning `NULL_BRUSH`, so "erase background" does nothing.

Return the solid brush of the color `RGB(245, 245, 245)`. You may also need to call `Invalidate` for that window after setting new text.